# Как вывести элементы списка с определенным промежутком времени?

Tags: python, list, время, range, countdown

У меня есть список countdown

```
countdown = list(range(1,11))
```

Я хочу вывести числа от 1 до 10 с промежутком в 2 секунды каждый. Как это осуществить?

Answer (score 2):

```
import time


for elem in range(1,11):
    print(elem)
    time.sleep(2)
```